# Registering Collections in Autofac 2.1.10 RC

Tags: autofac

I am upgrading code from Autofac 1.4 to 2.1.10 Release Candidate.

My module previously performed registration like this:

```
builder.RegisterCollection<IExceptionHandler>()
                .As<IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler>>()
                .FactoryScoped();
builder.Register<AspNetExceptionHandler>()
                .As<IExceptionHandler>()
                .MemberOf<IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler>>()
                .FactoryScoped();
```

Now, `RegisterCollection` has no parameterless overload. I don't care about assigning it a name. Assuming it's OK to just pass in `null`, my code looks like this in 2.1:

```
builder.RegisterCollection<IExceptionHandler>(null)
                .As<IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler>>()
                .InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<AspNetExceptionHandler>()
                .As<IExceptionHandler>()
                .MemberOf<IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler>>(null)
                .InstancePerDependency();
```

However, when I compile, I get the following error regarding `.MemberOf`:

> Using the generic method
>   'Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.MemberOf(Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder,
>   string)' requires '3' type arguments

I tried putting in a collection name instead of null, just in case, and that had no effect.

What's the proper way to register collections in 2.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, you just register a bunch of `IExceptionHandler` types, and then when you request an `IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler>` Autofac 2 will just take care of everything for you.

From the [NewInV2](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2) page:

```
builder.RegisterType<A1>().As<IA>();
builder.RegisterType<A2>().As<IA>();

var container = builder.Build();

// Contains an instance of both A1 and A2
Assert.AreEqual(2, container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IA>>().Count());
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that on NewInV2. Thanks, that appears to work.

I am left wondering, however, how I would create a named collection if I *did* want to.